# how to get text of the line by highlighted position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div which contains the long paragraph text. I have also a scrolling line which can be moved to up or down.
I want to get the text where its currently on, like in below screen you can see that the position of the line is on 3rd line. Basically the highlighted line is a div with absolute position. Please suggest how can I get the text which is highlighted.

Thanks

here is screenshot of the paragraph for clarification

[image]

actually that highlighted line is movable selection colored div can be moved with mouse to up or down, i want to get the text on which line of the paragraph it is.

there is a table like this struction

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <!-- here is the pragraph with many lines -->

    <div>In 20 years our technology will reach a level of personalization that will enhance every moment of our lives. We’ll be more physically comfortable with the furniture we sit on and the products we hold; only the most relevant and personalized information from friends and family will reach us; and our movement in the digital world will be near telepathic.</div>
</td>
<td>
    <!-- this is a div with absolute position to hightlight the line only -->
    <div id="highlightingline" style="border-spacing: 5px; background-color: rgb(200, 226, 235); position: absolute; width: 55%; float: left; margin-left: -795px; opacity: 0.5; margin-top: 111px; color: black; border-collapse: separate; border-color: gray;">&nbsp;</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Please note that i don't want to select the text by mouse selection, as its already working fine, i just want to get the highlight line text without mouse select. you can say, i want to get the text of the line where the highlighted line is over on the text.

Please have a look on this jsfiddle i have created a demo, look on this
scroll the content you will see highlighted line i want to get the text, which line / text / sentence is highlighted

http://jsfiddle.net/qbhNw/1/

Comment: Could you provide the markup for that text, it's hard to say something without it.

Comment: Sorry I don't actually know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/GYuBv/2/)

```
var text = "";
if (window.getSelection) {
    text = window.getSelection().toString();
} else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
    text = document.selection.createRange().text;
}

alert(text);
```

Comment: i dont want to select with mouse selection as its already working at me :) i want to select by highlighted div moving over the text

Comment: i want to select by highlighted div moving over the text... would you please elloborate

Comment: actually that highlighted line is movable selection colored div can be moved with mouse to up or down, i want to get the text on which line of the paragraph it is.

Comment: you can check which div's background color is the color you are seeing on highlighted text's and then you can get the html of it.

Comment: both are different div's and the div which contains the text its not colored, it only contains the text, the next div which is highlighting the line in text is a absolute positioned div.

Comment: @AshfaqAhmed can you please create a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)..? right now you are trying to explain the functionality in theory which is not helping us to solve the problem.

Comment: Please have a look on this jsfiddle i have created a demo, look on this scroll the content you will see highlighted line i want to get the text, which line / text / sentence is highlighted

http://jsfiddle.net/qbhNw/1/

Comment: ok i got what you are asking for. let me work on it a bit

Comment: @FurquanKhan thanks i am waiting for that :)